# Open-source image processing library that supports high level 3D algorithms?

Tags: open-source, image-processing, 3d

High, 
I need to do some image manipulations on CT volume images. Mainly segmentations.
Which open-source library supports 3D algorithms - Filtering, edge detection, deformable objects and so ?
Language is not an issue at the moment.

10x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try itk: http://www.itk.org/

Answer (score 2):

Check out CMTK (C++):

http://www.nitrc.org/projects/cmtk

Also note that nitrc.org is a good place to find more of this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

For purely 2D image processing then opencv/ivt/vxl
For 3d volume visualization then either the [osgvolume](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg/wiki/Community/Tasks/osgVolume) part of [openscenegraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) or [VTK](http://www.vtk.org)

Answer (score 1):

My company processes CT and MR medical images, to perform segmentation, and related shape measurement for industrial clients. We use (and contribute to) [VXL](http://vxl.sourceforge.net) as our underlying 2D and 3D image, math and geometry library.

[ITK](http://www.itk.org/) is also very good.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ with [http://www.amazon.com/Learning-OpenCV-Computer-Vision-Library/dp/0596516134](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)

Comment: I'm not familiar with CT volume images but i suppose OpenCV would be enough or maybe not? :/

Comment: As far as I know, OpenCV is not able to process 3D data. At least, that's not the primary focus of OpenCV.

For example, with volume datasets, you like to calculate the 3D gradients. Among other uses, this is required for proper lighting if visualized. Also, you might want to segment parts (e.g. a tumor) as a 3D surface from a volumetric dataset. I do not see OpenCV able to do this -- while ITK can. Well, ITK is ugly ugly ugly on the other hand, so maybe someone can suggest something else as well...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about medical CT (and not industrial inspection), you'll probably find [Debian Med](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianMed)'s list of open-source packages related to imaging ([apps](http://debian-med.alioth.debian.org/tasks/imaging), [libraries](http://debian-med.alioth.debian.org/tasks/imaging-dev)) well worth a browse.